# GoogleOAuth redirect URL, LocalServerReceiver port number

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-oauth

I have a java based web app which downloads youtube comments for a given video. It works all fine locally but when i deploy it to amazon clound stated giving me all the erros in the authentication process due to callback url issues.

```
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes).setCredentialDataStore(datastore)
            .build();

    // Build the local server and bind it to port xxxxx
    LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort( 15555 ).build(); 
    // Authorize.
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");
   );
    return credential;
```

Above   code snippet was taken from the youtube dev website.

My question is since the `localReciver` which gets the access token from the youtube, runs on port 15555, there's no way`localReceiver` is gonna get the response from youtube as only port 80 acessible from outside given my site is on amazon cloud..right?

So in other words if i had my redirect_uri as `redirect_uri=http://mysite.elasticbeanstalk.com:15555/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl`
, is not going to work since it's on port 15555. I'm trying to wrap my head over this to find a solutin. How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:
I authenticated locally, generated the token and copy the file to the server, and it works, although not sure if the refresh process it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using setHost?

```
new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setHost("myelasticbeanch.com").setPort(15555).build();
```